# Process.Start() Hangs Service When Command Waits for User Input

Tags: c#

I have an app where users can enter a dos command to be run at a later time by a service. Here is an example of what a user can enter:

[image]

This works well, but since a service runs the command, the `/Q` parameter must be there because there is no human interaction. I'm trying to figure out how the service can gracefully handle when the `/Q` is missing. As it stands now, the service actually hangs, and has to be stopped (a couple of times) and then started again. This happens because a command without `/Q` ends up waiting for user input.

This is the (slimmed-down) code to run a command:

```
using (Process process = new Process())
{
    string processOutput = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        process.StartInfo.FileName               = "file name (cmd in this case)";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments              = "parameters (with the \Q)";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute        = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError  = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput  = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        process.Start();

        processOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        process.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogException(ex);
    }
```

The catch block doesn't get hit. The service just hangs until I manually stop and start it.

Is it possible to handle this scenario so that the service doesn't hang? I'm not even sure what to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to add the `/Q` if it's not found:

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments.AddQuietSwitch();
```

**Extension Method:**

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> _quietSwitchMap =
    new Dictionary<string, string> { { "rmdir", "/Q" }, { "xcopy", "/y" } };

public static string AddQuietSwitch(this string input)
{
    var trimmedInput = input.Trim();
    var cmd = trimmedInput.Substring(0, trimmedInput.IndexOf(" "));

    string switch;
    if (!_quietSwitchMap.TryGetValue(cmd, out switch)) { return input; }
    if (trimmedInput.IndexOf(switch, 0,
        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > 0 { return input; }

    return input += string.Format(" {0}", _quietSwitchMap[cmd]);
}
```

Comment: Well, `/q` is specific to `rmdir`. `xcopy` wants `/y` instead, for instance.

Comment: As an addition: Please search case insensitively for both `/q` and `/Q`.

Comment: Actually, this won't work because a user can enter *any* DOS command, and most of them will NOT require quiet mode.

Comment: Ah, nice. So basically just look for rmdir or xcopy (and possibly anything else that would need quiet mode), and add /Q (or /y) if it's missing. Actually, it would be good to detect this in the UI and not allow rmdir or xcopy without the quiet command.

Comment: @BobHorn, that's right; it's fully configurable via the dictionary.

Comment: +1 as this is a good workaround. I would still like to know if there is a way to catch this because perhaps there is another command (that I'm not thinking of) that may need the quiet mode. I don't want that to hang the service either. If no one can come up with a way to catch this, I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could append

echo y | rmdir ...

to the command when /Q is not provided.

Comment: Ah, I see. The prompt will happen and the echo Y will answer yes to the prompt. +1 for the interesting tip, but it still doesn't cover the scenario where something other than rmdir or xcopy is used.

Comment: Note: There is a risk here that `echo Y` could answer a question other than quiet mode. For example, I tried an xcopy and this prompt came up: `Does C:\temp\AnotherTemp\snuh.txt specify a file name or directory name on the target (F = file, D = directory)?` `echo y` caused `Y` to be the answer to a question that was expecting F or D.